# Python Stratified KFold

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation

I have a dataframe `df` that looks something like this. I'm trying to model this data using logistic regression, where the features (f1-f6) are binary and the target is also binary.

```
f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 target
0  0  1  1  0  1  0 
0  1  0  0  0  0  0 
0  1  1  1  1  0  1 
1  1  0  0  1  0  1
```

A stratified K fold from my understanding with make sure that there is a decently even distribution of labels in the training set and test set.
But I want to make sure the distribution is even for each feature is also even.

For example I can have a cross table of a certain feature like so:

```
  target   0 1
f1 
0        240 125
1         11 18
```

As you can see f1 being 1 has a small amount of occurences and I want to make sure that it's shown in both the test and train set reasonabbly. I want to make sure of this for all features.

I did something like below (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html). But I think this only makes sure the labels are even not accounting for feature imbalances. How can I do cross validation on the data to have a decently even distribbution across all the features/labels?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
X = df[['f1','f2','f3','f4','f5','f6']]
y = df['target']
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2)
skf.get_n_splits(X, y)

StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
     X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
     y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have utilized a method that Jason Brownlee, Machine Learning Mastery, explains and shows a nice simple working example of:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import pandas as pd

data = {'f1': [0,0,0,1],
        'f2': [0,1,1,1],
        'f3': [1,0,1,0],
        'f4': [1,0,1,0],
        'f5': [0,0,1,1],
        'f6': [1,0,0,0],
        'target': [0,0,1,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['f1','f2','f3','f4','f5','f6','target'])

print(df)

kfold = KFold(3, True, 1)

for train, test in kfold.split(data):
    print('train: %s, test: %s' % (train, test))

# scikit-learn k-fold cross-validation
from numpy import array
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

# data sample
data = array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0])

# prepare cross validation
kfold = KFold(3, shuffle=True, random_state=1, )

# enumerate splits
for train, test in kfold.split(data):
    print('train: %s, test: %s' % (data[train], data[test]))
```

https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/

Here is the output from PyCharm on Macbook Pro using Python 3.8:

[image]